# Why did only Luke record that one of the prisoners started believing in Christ?

Tags: luke, crucifixion, bible

Luke 23:26-43 I was wondering why Luke (to my knowledge) was the only one who said that one of the prisoners started believing in Christ and others like Matthew said that they both heaped insults on him

Comment: There are thousands of differences between the gospel accounts.  They are four independent accounts and this record different fact from different perspectives.  The same could be asked of any of the other many differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll repeat what I said on the [other question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/91268/58339), but I'll add a point:

Luke 1:1-4 New King James Version

> 1 Inasmuch as many have taken in hand to set in order **a narrative** of
> those things which have been fulfilled among us, 2 just as those
> who **from the beginning were eyewitnesses** and ministers of the word
> delivered them to us, 3 it seemed good to me also, having had
> perfect understanding of all things from the very first, **to write to
> you an orderly account**, most excellent Theophilus, 4 that you may know
> the certainty of those things in which you were instructed.

1. **Eyewitness Testimony.** Luke was not a direct eyewitness of the events he recorded in his own Gospel! It's possible, and likely, that Luke had access to sources or eyewitness accounts that provided details the others didn't have. The other Gospel writers likely didn't have the same sources Luke had, if any. Luke, who was known to be a **meticulous researcher and careful historian**, may have incorporated this specific account based on the reliable testimony he received.
2. **Different people have different perspectives.** Luke's Gospel is filled with themes of repentance, forgiveness, salvation, particularly for the lowly or sinful individuals. (See how he included the women finding Jesus' tomb first. Luke 24:1-12) Not many people would take the time to show the good side of a criminal. However, **perhaps Luke thought it was worth showing the worth of a criminal.**